# Pass an id to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to pass an `id` that I get by parsing from the url to an anchor tag. Below is my code which will get the `id` by parsing it from the url.

Let's take an example, suppose if if `id is 123` then my anchor tag should look like this-

```
<a href="some_url&userId=123"> something here </a>
```

But somehow with the below code it is not working. Can anyone explain me what wrong I am doing.

```
<body>
<script>

var id = getUrlParameters()["ID"];    
id = unescape(id);


</script>

// Below things doesn't work with the way I am doing.
<a href="some_url&userId=id"></a>

</body>
```

I am not able to pass the id to anchor tag successfully. What wrong I am doing here?

**Updated Code:-**

The actual anchor tag is something like this-

```
<a href="https://sox.host.net:7020/ps/sox/HRS_HRAM.JN_HRS_CE.GBL&userId=id"></a>
```

Now I need to replace `id` withing the anchor tag with `123` basis on whatever the value of `id` is.

**Updated Question:-**

I am trying to pass the variable value to an anchor tag. I have a script in Javascript that will get the value from the url. So suppose in the below code,

```
value of variable id is 54321
```

Then my anchor tag should look like this-

```
<a href="some_url&jobId=54321"><img src="url" style="border:none" onmouseover="this.src='url'" onmouseout="this.src='url'"/></a>
```

But suppose the `value of variable id is 2612`, then my anchor tag should look like this-

```
<a href="some_url&jobId=2612"><img src="url" style="border:none" onmouseover="this.src='url'" onmouseout="this.src='url'"/></a>
```

With the below code, I have, its not working for me. I am not able to pass the id variable value to an anchor tag successfully.

```
<body>
<script>
function getParameters() {

 // some code

}

var id = getParameters()["ID"];    
id = unescape(id);

// some code

</script>

<a href="some_url&jobId=id"><img src="url" style="border:none" onmouseover="this.src='url'" onmouseout="this.src='url'"/></a>

</body>
```

Comment: This code never sets the `href` attribute.

Comment: I have removed few lines of code to make it simpler to understand. Just edited it.

Comment: Didn't I see this same code a few days ago asking why a `<script>` tag wasn't working?

Comment: Why are you creating a script element? Didn't you say you wanted to generate an anchor?

Comment: That thing I figured out what was the problem. Now I am facing some other problem.

Comment: I thought we can pass the id directly in anchor tag?

Comment: This does not look like a properly formed URL: "some_url&userId=123". I think you mean this: "some_url?userId=123". If you want to pass another key-value pair, then you use the "&": "some_url?userId=123&name=Fritz"

Comment: some_url has some extra things Jeffman that will cover your point but I have removed those just to make it more simple and clear what I am looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please see my answer, if it answered your question then please accept it. For your new question, please ask a separate question.

Comment: you need  to pass like this  <a href="some_url?jobId=id">  first time  you need to use ?  after that you can use &

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `&` instead of `?` which will cause an error.

Try this:

```
<a href="some_url?userId=123"> something here </a>
```

#### Explanation

All i did was change the `&` to a `?`.

Remember these two rules:

- You should use the `?` symbol to connect GET values to a url
- You should use the `&` symbol to connect GET values to each other

I hope this helped you out, and feel free to ask for further help!

Comment: Not it hasn't answer my question. The URL that I am using is same as I have provided above. I will update the question with the actual url again.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you are sending is called `userId` and the one you try to retrieve is `ID`. You should use `var id = getUrlParameters()["userId"]` instead.

EDIT:
If your problem is just passing `id` as an argument to the `href`, try this:

First, add a tag id to you link tag:

```
<a href="some_url&userId=id" id="a_tag_id_here">...</a>
```

Then, add the `href` with JQuery, using your `id` variable:

```
$('a_tag_id_here').attr('href','https://sox.host.net:7020/ps/sox/HRS_HRAM.JN_HRS_CE.GBL&userId='+id);
```

It's up to you to decide what should trigger this command. If you want it to be set right after the loading of the page, just put this code inside this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // code here
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question with some more details how my url will look like.

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T Not sure I understand 100% what you want, but I edited the answer based on what you explained with your update

Comment: I have updated my question again to make more sense to you. I guess you are not able to understand my question yet. Let me know if it is still not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var getid= /*your id*/
```

then get the url from anchor tag using `.attr('href')` method replace the part after = ,using `split('=')` method.

forex:

```
var temp=$('a').attr('href').split('=')[0];
$('a').attr('href',temp+'='+getid);
```