# passing variable value to href argument in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to pass the variable value to href argument in anchor tag.

```
<body>
<script>
var id = "10";
$('a_tag_id').attr('href','http://www.google.com&jobid='+id);
</script>


<a id="a_tag_id">something_here</a>
</body>
```

I want anchor tag to look like this after the above code is executed.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com&jobid=10">something_here</a>
```

But somehow the above code is not working. Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: `$('a_tag_id')` should be `$('#a_tag_id')`

Comment: to pass the value in href tag    < href="http://yourdomain.com?myid='1'?yourid='2'" >Something </a>

Comment: to pass the value in href tag    < href="http://yourdomain.com?myid='1'?yourid='2'" >Something </a>  first time you need to pass ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have miss `#` in jQuery selector, and insert the code inside the document.ready to make that your script work when the page is ready

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var id = "10";
   $('#a_tag_id').attr('href','http://www.google.com&jobid='+id);
});
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/chfvk/)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `#` for the id. Try using `$('#a_tag_id')`. Use an `?` before your first query string variable instead of `&`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#` for `id` selctor

```
$('#a_tag_id').attr('href','http://www.google.com&jobid='+id);
   ^
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsX62/)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the jquery like this

```
 $('#a_tag_id').attr('href','http://www.google.com&jobid='+id);
```

Answer (score 0):

When your Javascript is executed, the `a` tag might not exist yet.

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = "10";
    $('#a_tag_id').attr('href','http://www.google.com&jobid='+id);
});
```

Also, it should be `#a_tag_id` to match the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#a_tag_id').attr('href','http://www.google.com?jobid='+id);
```

The selector should be for id '#', and the querystring starts with "?".

BTW: Isn't this question following up on your last question: [Pass an id to anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935324/pass-an-id-to-anchor-tag) ?